# I created a List Container class in C++ and it's not working as expected

Tags: c++, list, containers, nodes, class-template

So first I created a struct to contain the following:

```
template <class T>
struct ListNode 
{
    unsigned int id;

    T data;
    ListNode *next_left;
    ListNode *next_right;
};
```

And a class with the following:

```
template <class T>
class List 
{

public:

    unsigned int id_count;
    ListNode<T> *tail;

    List()
    { 
        tail = NULL;
        id_count = 0;
    }

    unsigned int add(T item)
    {
        id_count += 1;

        ListNode<T> *n = new ListNode<T>;
        n->id = id_count;
        n->data = item;
        n->next_left = tail;
        n->next_right = NULL;

        tail = n;
        if (n->next_left != NULL)
            n->next_left->next_right = n;

        return id_count;
    }

    ListNode<T> *getNode(unsigned int id)
    {
        bool found = false;
        ListNode<T> *np = tail;
        while(np != NULL)
        {
            if (np->id == id)
            {
                found = true;
                return np;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                np = np->next_left;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

Here is a link to the exact code of main.cpp: http://pastebin.com/fHhsvd9A

So in my main.cpp I create a List instance and a Node pointer:

```
List<F3D_model> GameEntities;
ListNode<F3D_model> *np;
```

Then I create two model class instances of the F3D_model Class and add them to the List intsance I created:

```
F3D_model model;
model.create();

F3D_model model2;
model2.create();

GameEntities.add(model);
GameEntities.add(model2);
```

Print models' information:

```
Created with ID: 1
Created with ID: 2

Model 1 Address: 07091F28
Model 2 Address: 070919D0

Model 1 Angle: 0
Model 2 Angle: 0

Tail ID: 2
Tail Data: 0
Tail Address: 070919D0
```

Code used to print information:

```
printf("Created with ID: %i\n",GameEntities.add(model));
printf("Created with ID: %i\n",GameEntities.add(model2));

printf("Model 1 Address: %p\n",GameEntities.getNode(1));
printf("Model 2 Address: %p\n",GameEntities.getNode(2));
printf("----------------\n");
printf("Model 1 Data: %i\n",GameEntities.getNode(1)->data.angle);
printf("Model 2 Data: %i\n",GameEntities.getNode(2)->data.angle);
printf("----------------\n");
printf("Tail ID: %i\n",(GameEntities.tail->id));
printf("Tail Data: %i\n",(GameEntities.tail->data.angle));
printf("Tail Address: %p\n",(GameEntities.tail));
printf("----------------\n");
```

( angle is a public var in F3D_model class )

Everything looks right. 
So I have a keypress event where I add a value to the models' angle.

```
GameEntities.getNode(1)->data.angle += 60;
GameEntities.getNode(2)->data.angle += 60;
```

and then it prints again the values.

So the problem is that when I press the key it prints the same, as if I hadn't added the values.

BUT when I press the key it does move the model on the screen, so it is actually adding the values. And when I change the type from F3D_model to int and do the same process, it works just fine.

SO my question is why isn't it working when I use the F3D_model, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Can you provide the code that prints the values and what do you mean "when you press a key", is that like a menu?

Comment: @bkVnet what I mean with "when you press a key" is that I have a KeyPressed SFML event that adds to the angle variable whenever i hit "space"

Comment: Ok, it could may be a problem when you print the values. When i tried your code it works fine after adding the values. Besides if the model moves on the screen, you know the values are added.

Comment: @bkVnet I edited the question with the code that prints the values, and what class did you use instead of F3D_model?

Comment: I suppose you defined F3D_model class, so i create a class with that name and added a public int angle data member.

Comment: @bkVnet It does add the value, but I can't get the angle

Comment: The problem is not reproducable as it stands. May be you should edit the code in your question to show the exact sequence of execution(when is the information printed, when are values added), it might help.

Comment: @bkVnet I edited with a link to the code.

Comment: Longshot: is it possible that the angle isn't an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, it sounds like the issue is just how you're printing the angle:

```
printf("Model 1 Data: %i\n",GameEntities.getNode(1)->data.angle);
printf("Model 2 Data: %i\n",GameEntities.getNode(2)->data.angle);
```

You've used `%i` which is an integer format specifier. You've said it prints what you expect when you change the definition of `angle` to be an `int`. If you change the format string to `%f` to print a float, or print `static_cast<int>( GameEntities.getNode(1)->data.angle )` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The  problem I can think of is that you use model and model2 when printing values, but you should use your nodes instead, because they are copies of the created models.

You can store pointers to models instead of models themselves in your list, to avoid copying models.

Comment: Well, I didn't use model and model2, I get the values from the Node's data.